# Filter out rows from two arrays where the same column value is in both arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

I have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
$array1 = [
    ['id' => '434b5g6', 'unique_id' => 'banana', 'level' => 8],
    ['id' => 'bfrfnr', 'unique_id' => 'apple', 'level' => 4],
    ['id' => 'yt347509', 'unique_id' => 'grapefruit', 'level' => 9],
    ['id' => '456645', 'unique_id' => 'strawberry', 'level' => 1],
];

$array2 = [
    ['id' => 'gon235g6', 'unique_id' => 'strawberry', 'level' => 8],
    ['id' => 'bfrfnr', 'unique_id' => 'apple', 'level' => 4],
    ['id' => 'logujtng9', 'unique_id' => 'grapefruit', 'level' => 6],
    ['id' => '07yburhg', 'unique_id' => 'pinapple', 'level' => 1],
];
```

I need a way to remove the rows containing the same `unique_id` value in both arrays so that I'm left with 2 arrays which only contain elements that do not exist in the other.

Desired results as two separate arrays:

```
[['id' => '434b5g6', 'unique_id' => 'banana', 'level' => 8]]
```

and

```
[['id' => '07yburhg', 'unique_id' => 'pinapple', 'level' => 1]]
```

I know there is `array_diff()`, but this only works for single level arrays. I'm using multi-level arrays and only targeting the `unique_id` column for comparisons.

Comment: Are the entries actually different and only the `unique_id` is the same, or is the entire entry identical across both arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the unique ids out of both arrays.
2. Calculate their difference (items that are not in both).
3. Filter the original arrays to items that are in the diff.

Here a sample for PHP 5.3+:

```
$uniqueIds1 = array_map(function ($item) { return $item['unique_id']; }, $array1);
$uniqueIds2 = array_map(function ($item) { return $item['unique_id']; }, $array2);

$reallyUniqueIds = array_merge(array_diff($uniqueIds1, $uniqueIds2), array_diff($uniqueIds2, $uniqueIds1));

$filteredArray1 = array_filter($array1, function ($item) use ($reallyUniqueIds) {
    return in_array($item['unique_id'], $reallyUniqueIds);
});
$filteredArray2 = array_filter($array2, function ($item) use ($reallyUniqueIds) {
    return in_array($item['unique_id'], $reallyUniqueIds);
});
```

---

Explanation:

```
array_map(function ($item) { return $item['unique_id']; }, $array1)
```

This just extracts all `unique_id` values into an array like `array('banana', 'apple', ...)`.

```
array_merge(array_diff($uniqueIds1, $uniqueIds2), array_diff($uniqueIds2, $uniqueIds1));
```

This creates the diffs between the arrays both ways and merges them into one array, like:

```
array('banana', 'apple')
array('strawberry', 'apple')
-> array('banana', 'strawberry')
```

See [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/array_diff).

Then finally, this goes through the original arrays again to filter out all elements whose `unique_key` is not in the array we created in the previous step:

```
array_filter($array1, function ($item) use ($reallyUniqueIds) {
    return in_array($item['unique_id'], $reallyUniqueIds);
})
```

This just uses a custom callback function for `array_filter`, which tells it to filter items where `in_array($item['unique_id'], $reallyUniqueIds)` is `false`.

Comment: It all makes sense and works until line 4 but after that im actually confused. Is it possible to explain what exactly is going on.

Comment: The difference needs to be calculated in both directions, I think in the code, it's only done in one direction, from array1 against array2 but not array2 against array1.

Comment: @red Added some more explanation.

Comment: @Deceze: Yeah I first tried similar to yours but then wanted to make it possible to have an N amount of arrays to operate upon. But the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8653629/367456) is not really readable. It's a pity codefrog removed his website and array class.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print_r(array_unique($arr1 + $arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $array1 as $key1 => $innerarray1 ) {

  foreach ( $array2 as $key2 => $innerarray2 ) {

    if ($innerarray1['unique_id'] == $innerarray2['unique_id']) {

       unset($array2[$key2]);           
 }
```

}

Now $array2 will have non common unique_id values in it

Answer (score 0):

1. join all "unique_id" across all arrays.
2. filter out duplicates to get uniques.
3. filter all arrays based on the uniques.

The following is a function that operates on one, two or more arrays, first parameter is the key that is to be used for the unique id, any additional one is another array. Usage:

```
list($unique1, $unique2) = joined_uniquekey('unique_id', $array1, $array2);
```

Code:

```
function joined_uniquekey($key, $array1, $array2)
{
    $arrays = func_get_args(); $key = array_shift($arrays);
    $vkey = function($v) use ($key) {return $v[$key];};
    $map = function($f) {return function(array $as) use ($f) {return array_map($f, $as);};};
    $keys = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map($map($vkey), $arrays)));
    foreach($keys as $k => $c) if ($c > 1) unset($keys[$k]);
    $hkey = function($v) use ($key, $keys) {return isset($keys[$v[$key]]);};
    $filter = function($f) {return function(array $a) use ($f) {return array_filter($a, $f);};};
    return array_map($filter($hkey), $arrays);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_udiff()` will directly return what you need with no data preparation at all.

Declare the columns to be compared in the custom callback function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fGGGp))

```
// unique in $array1
var_export(array_udiff($array1, $array2, fn($a, $b) => $a['unique_id'] <=> $b['unique_id']));
// unique in $array2
var_export(array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => $a['unique_id'] <=> $b['unique_id']));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '434b5g6',
    'unique_id' => 'banana',
    'level' => 8,
  ),
)

array (
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '07yburhg',
    'unique_id' => 'pinapple',
    'level' => 1,
  ),
)
```