# comparing two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, union, intersect

I have an array in PHP $array which has elements like

```
$array['id'].. $array['name'] $array['class']
```

I have another array called $array1 which has element only $array1['uid'].
I want to match these two array on the basis of `$array['id'] and $array['uid']`
such that I want to get elements $array['id'] not equal to $array['uid']`
Is there any builtin function in PHP, I can do that in for each loop with my custome function , but is there any function?

Input is if $array has id=2,4,5,6 and $array has uid=2,4 then I should get $array id=5,6

Data in $array  looks like this

```
{
      "name": "abc", 
      "id": "37402526"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "def", 
      "id": "506768590"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "hij", 
      "id": "526405977"
   }
```

And $array 1 like this

```
{

      "id": "37402526"
    }, 
    {

      "id": "506768590"
    }, 
    {
      "
      "id": "526405977"
   }
```

Comment: Is your array multi-dimensional? Can you post a `<pre>` formatted `print_r()` output of the said array? (and the expected output, too)

Comment: in_array($array[id] , $array1 ); return true if any matches.

Comment: @AmalMurali I have edited the question.. both are single dimensional

Comment: @user1765876: It's still not clear how the array looks like. Can't you post a `print_r($array)` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali please see

Comment: possible duplicate of [comparing two arrays in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101557/comparing-two-arrays-in-php)

Comment: See `array_udiff()` @ [Filter out rows from two arrays where the same column value is in both arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73553340/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rewrite your code, to have the id's in array keys, than you could use array_diff_key():

```
$array = array(
    '12' => array('name' => 'abc'),
    '34' => array('name' => 'def')
);

$array2 = array('12' => true);

$result = array_diff_key($array, $array2);
```

Otherwise you can use array_udiff():

```
function my_id_cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['id'], $b['id']);
}

$result = array_udiff($array, $array1, 'my_id_cmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is just in the format you used as example, then it is simple :

```
$array['id'] = implode(',', array_diff(explode(',', $array['id']), explode(',', $array1['uid'])));
```

Regards.

Comment: I lose the data in $array as it is multi dimensional

Comment: This code snippet just affects the 'id' key so no data lose as you are saying. Strange!